# React-Router-Dom <Link> not render page

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router-dom

I'm building a practice app that uses Unsplash to render users photos. I'm using React and Redux. With `react-router-dom`, I'm trying to follow the docs but I find it very confusing to set up. Here's what I have so far. When I click on a result out of a returned list of results from a search, I want it to render a user page profile.

index.js (make sure I have `react-router-do` set up correctly):

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
// import store from './app/store';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import reducers from "./app/reducers/rootReducer"; 
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

const storeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

const store = createStore(reducers, storeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk)));

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Top component `App`

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Images from "./app/components/Images";
import Search from "./app/components/Search";
import UserProfile from "./app/components/UserProfile";

import "./App.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Search />
      <Images />
      <Router>
        <Route link="/userProfile">
          <UserProfile />
        </Route>
      </Router>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

`search` (parent component to `searchResults` where  exists):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { queryAction } from "../actions/queryAction";
import SearchResults from "./SearchResults";

const Search = (props) => {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
  console.log(props.searches);

  const searchPhotos = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("submitting form");
    props.queryAction(query);
  };

  const showUsers = (user, e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
       console.log(user)
  
  };

  return (
    <>
      <form className="form" onSubmit={searchPhotos}>
        <label className="label" htmlFor="query">
          {" "}
        </label>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="query"
          className="input"
          placeholder={`Try "dog" or "apple"`}
          value={query}
          onChange={(e) => setQuery(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button type="submit" className="button">
          Search
        </button>
      </form>

      <SearchResults results={props.searches} showUsers={showUsers} />
    </>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    searches: state.searches,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    queryAction: (entry) => dispatch(queryAction(entry)),
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Search);
```

`searchResults`:

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { getUserAction } from "../actions/getUserAction";
import { connect } from "react-redux";


const SearchResults = (props) => {
  const { results } = props.results.searches;

  const handleClick = (result, e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    props.getUser(result.username);
  };
  return (
    <>
      {results &&
        results.map((result, id) => {
          return (
            <div key={id}>
              <Router>
                <Link to="/userProfile" onClick={(e) => handleClick(result, e)}>
                  {result.username}
                </Link>
              </Router>
            </div>
          );
        })}
    </>
  );
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    getUser: (query) => dispatch(getUserAction(query)),
  };
};

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(SearchResults);
```

and finally the `UserProfile` component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const UserProfile = props => {
  
   console.log(props)
    return (
        <div>
        
        </div>
    );
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        user: state.users 
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(UserProfile);
```

Comment: Once you wrap your component with the BrowserRouter, you don't need to do it again. I think you meant to wrap your routes in the App component with the Switch component instead.

Answer (score 0):

app component

```
import React from "react";
import { Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Images from "./app/components/Images";
import Search from "./app/components/Search";
import UserProfile from "./app/components/UserProfile";

import "./App.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Search />
      <Images />
      <Switch>  
        <Route path="/userProfile/:username">
          <UserProfile />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

SearchResults component

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const SearchResults = (props) => {
  const { results } = props.results.searches;

  const handleClick = (result, e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    props.getUser(result.username);
  };
  return (
    <>
      {results &&
        results.map((result, id) => {
          return (
            <div key={id}>
                <Link to={`/userProfile/${result.username}`}>
                  {result.username}
                </Link>
            </div>
          );
        })}
    </>
  );
};


export default SearchResults;
```

UserProfile component

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getUserAction } from "../actions/getUserAction";

const UserProfile = props => {
  
   useEffect(() => {
      props.getUserAction(props.match.params.username)
   },[])

   console.log(props)
    return (
        <div>
          {props.user
            ? <div>{user.username}</div>
            : <div>Loading...</div>
          }
        </div>
    );
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        user: state.users 
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    getUser: (query) => dispatch(getUserAction(query)),
  };
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(UserProfile);
```

Edit: Add a param to your link and remove the onclick. Update the Route to expect a :username param. You can access the param through props in UserProfile component.

Make sure to perform the action or access state when mounting the UserProfile component so you have some data when it renders.

Edit 2: Added UserProfile component to answer. You want to dispatch your action when the component is mounting. Also, set a ternary to show "Loading..." if state.user isn't done being fetched.

Comment: When I click on a result, still not linking to a new page (/userProfile). Nothing happens. I tried restating `yarn start`. Any ideas? Does it have something to do that these are click links?

Comment: Yeah, link does not have on onclick. Instead, you can pass a query param like the result id. Then inside your userProfile component, `mapStateToProps` to pull the right object/user using the id.

Comment: Do you mind expanding on what that would look like?

Comment: I edited the Link and Route snippet above to take params. Also, here is an example from the docs on how to access the query params https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/component

Comment: Sorry, still not getting it. All I see in those docs is `component={}` but no way to access the redux store in `<Link>`

Comment: Added a the UserProfile component and a second edit to the answer.